# Why is the derivative called derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, soft-question, terminology, math-history

What is the historical reason for this term?

Derivative represents slope function of curve. I am not getting why  this term make sense?

Comment: For "integral", see the linked post. *Derivative* is from the French term *fonction dérivéee*, due to Lagrange. See [Théorie des fonctions analytiques (1797)](https://books.google.it/books?id=15IKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA17), page 17.

Comment: Terms have often starnhe history : [differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Differentiation) and [integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#History) was modern term (originating from Leibniz and its school) for the two fundamental processes of calculus.

Comment: Only a half-duplicate. The question to which it links does not provide much information on the etymology of "derivative".

Comment: I have edited it.